# Ubuntu 16.04: Oracle JDK 9 is NOT installed

Tags: java, ubuntu

Every time I try to install something from terminal this message pops up to me. Meanwhile I have my Java installed right:

```
download failed   
Oracle JDK 9 is NOT installed.  
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java9-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1  
Errors were encountered while processing:  
 oracle-java9-installer  
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Please can someone help me solve this; it's really annoying.

Comment: Are you following this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-get-on-ubuntu-16-04?

Comment: The problem is that Oracle retired parts of `java.net` without properly thinking things through regarding breaking links, etc (just like they did when they retired `sun.com`). Until third parties update their links (or Oracle fixes the mess they created), you'll probably need to do this manually. See http://jdk.java.net/9/

Comment: Great, can you explain to me what to do and how to install the zip file probably?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get purge oracle-java9-installer
```

solved my issue. 
Later I also changed Ubuntu Software center server to "Main Server".

Answer (score 2):

Actually I hit the issue after resolving the wine installation on my `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS` box. The wine issue I resolved using the below link.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/935050/unknown-error-class-keyerror-the-cache-has-no-package-named-wine1-6-i38

So that landed me to this post. But I was not able to install the java from apt packages. It threw me errors. Then I realized it was the issue of having multiple Java instances on my system. I already had Oracle Java 9 installed. I just needed to change  the current verions using the command

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

So if any body hits the error, you can try setting this.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error so using this command first i removed Java 9

```
sudo apt remove oracle-java9-installer
```

Then I made Java 8 as default

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

After this if you try to install other software it will work or you can also upgrade Java 8 to Java 9.

Comment: I'm on ubuntu 17.04 and can't get it work. The error persist.

Answer (score 1):

First, add Oracle's PPA, then update your package repository.

```
$sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
$sudo apt-get update
```

To install JDK 9, use the following command:

```
$sudo apt-get install oracle-java9-installer
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what steps you have tried already to install it but the link below is a fairly well explained description of how to install the JDK on Ubuntu. I've always installed the JDK through the webupd8team's ppa and its worked for me so far :)

A note about the link, it suggests setting the home variable, this may be necessary for you but I've never had to it manually and it's worked so give it a quick check before setting the home variable yourself.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-get-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: The thing i was upgrading my system and my laptop turned off without completing the upgrade and my wifi screwed up, i fixed it and now it's this java problem. Even the link you gave me if i do "sudo apt-get install default-jre" it won't let me install anything giving me same error message I'm just stuck can't install anything.

Comment: Is this only happening for JDK 9? Have you tried installing an older JDK such as 8? Also, does 'sudo apt-get update' work by any chance?

Comment: Ye i tried all versions i think i need to remove all jdk versions and re-install only one probably and idk the steps, and ye the update code-line working fine.

Comment: Removing all java version may be helpful, it could be some odd dependencies at play here. Just to clarify as I'm not sure what else it could be, you've definitely added the webupd8team ppa right?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem removing all java versions and purging them and re-installing them again probably, thanks everyone who tried to help.

Comment: You should mark your answer as accepted if it solved your particular problem. Also upvote those answers that you found useful for your question.

Answer (score 0):

### Completely removal criteria:

To remove Oracle JDK completely, run the commands below:

```
sudo apt-get remove oracle-java9-installer
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove oracle-java9-installer
sudo apt-get purge oracle-java9-installer
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove oracle-java9-installer
```

### Resource Link:

https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/trusty/tomcat7?action=remove

After that, install jdk9 using the following command:

### Install JDK9 in Ubuntu:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java9-installer
```

### Make it as default:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java9-set-default
```

### Resource Link:

http://zakirrizvi.blogspot.com/2017/10/install-jdk9-in-ubuntu.html

Comment: download failed
Oracle JDK 9 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java9-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java9-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: @stevematdavies Please go through this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/938314/cant-install-oracle-jdk-9

Comment: @stevematdavies do you have another jdk versions installed?